# Addevent listener prevent regex function

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a form and a button. The goal of function is when a user inputs submission (yourstorehere.com) this will concatenate the submission with a url then redirect. It was working fine until I add the addEventListener. Its returning the unknown.com but I wouls like it to concatenate the user submission with the url. Any ideas?

Input form

```
<form id="url">
        <input class="square-form" type="text" name="urlName" placeholder="yourstorehere.com">
        <button class="button-width" onclick="return myFunction()">Connect with Square</button>
    </form>
```

Javascript function

```
 function myFunction() {
            let myForm = document.getElementById("url").addEventListener("submit", myFunction);
            let formData = new FormData(myForm);
            EndOfUrl = sanitizeDomainInput(formData.get("urlName"));
            newUrl = redirectLink(EndOfUrl);
            window.location.href = newUrl;
            return false;
        }

    function sanitizeDomainInput(input) {
        input = input || 'unknown.com'
        if (input.startsWith('http://')) {
            input = input.substr(7)
        }
        if (input.startsWith('https://')) {
            input = input.substr(8)
        }
        var regexp = new RegExp(/^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/)
        return regexp.test(input) ? input : 'unknown.com'
    }

    function redirectLink(domain) {
        return `https://dashboard.getorda.com/signup/?state=${domain}`;
    }
```

Comment: `let myForm = document.getElementById("url").addEventListener("submit", myFunction);` INSIDE `myfunction` look wrong - for one thing, `addEventListener` returns undefined ... so `let formData = new FormData(myForm);` is `let formData = new FormData(undefined);` - for another, adding an event listener that executes the function where the addeventlistner is added ....

Comment: Ok so we are returning undefined. How do i adjust this?

Comment: you can't ... that's what addEventListener returns

Answer (score 0):

Add your event listener outside the function; and change myFunction to get you the element you need and not the event listener

```
document.getElementById("url").addEventListener("submit", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    let myForm = document.getElementById("url");
    let formData = new FormData(myForm);
    EndOfUrl = sanitizeDomainInput(formData.get("urlName"));
    newUrl = redirectLink(EndOfUrl);
    window.location.href = newUrl;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but still doesn't seem to be getting the users value

Comment: Ok update, its working on my VS code but for some reason it's not functioning correctly when adding raw js and html to wordpress

Comment: @flexwithfrank wordpress dosen't let you add script tags easily. Here is a short guide that might help you get it running in wordpress. https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-custom-javascript-to-your-wordpress-site--cms-34368